# Monitor mode / packet injection not working

Tags: network-programming, scapy, packet, packet-injection

I'm trying to inject a packet to the wifi network in monitor mode using scapy. Here is my code

```
from scapy.all import *
 
class Dot11EltRates(Packet):
    """ Our own definition for the supported rates field """
    name = "802.11 Rates Information Element"
    # Our Test STA supports the rates 6, 9, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48 and 54 Mbps
    supported_rates = [0x0c, 0x12, 0x18, 0x24, 0x30, 0x48, 0x60, 0x6c]
    fields_desc = [ByteField("ID", 1), ByteField("len", len(supported_rates))]
    for index, rate in enumerate(supported_rates):
        fields_desc.append(ByteField("supported_rate{0}".format(index + 1),
                                     rate))
src = "4c:5e:0c:11:01:95"
dst = "d0:39:57:b8:a8:bf"
packet = Dot11(
    addr1=src,
    addr2=dst,
    addr3=src) / Dot11AssoReq(
            cap=0x1100, listen_interval=0x00a) / Dot11Elt(
                ID=0, info="MY_BSSID")
    packet /= Dot11EltRates()
    sendp(packet, iface="wlan0mon")
    packet.show()
```

I checked the rates on both wifi cards using `iw list`

Also, both cards support monitor mode and packet injection: checked with aircrack-ng suite `sudo aireplay-ng <interface> --test` - both show

> Injection is working!

And yet, when I inject a packet with one card its only visible on that computer, the other doesn't see it (I'm using wireshark for this), I have set both wifi cards to the same channel and baudrate.

What am I missing?

Comment: Remember that most Wi-Fi chipsets do not actually support monitor or promiscuous mode, and most give no error when attempting it. Verify that yours supports it or not by searching the chipset manufacturer, not depending on an application to tell you.

Comment: Its the chipset that matters and not the driver, right?

Comment: Yes. A driver cannot make a chipset do something that it cannot do.

Comment: Okay so I haven't found any explicit statements about monitor/injection mode, so I used aireplay-ng to inject deauth packets, and it was succesfull on one card but not on the other. so now, I guess, I have one that can inject and the other that can monitor (see those injected deauth packets). Do you think this is a good enough test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm happy to share the solution that I came up with. Its in C, I'm using raw sockets and radiotap header to craft a legal packet. The networking cards that I initially used did not fully support packet injection. So, now im using Atheros AR9271 to inject packets and Realtek RTL8812BU for sniffing. Anyways here is the injection code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

struct radiotap_header
{
    unsigned char it_version;
    unsigned char it_pad;
    unsigned short it_len;
    unsigned int it_present;
};

struct ieee80211_header
{
    unsigned short frame_control;
    unsigned short duration_id;
    unsigned char addr1[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    unsigned char addr2[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    unsigned char addr3[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    unsigned short seq_ctrl;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <interface>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_ll sll;
    char *interface = argv[1];

    sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0); 
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct ifreq if_idx;
    memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, interface, IFNAMSIZ - 1);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0)
    {
        perror("ioctl");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&sll, 0, sizeof(sll));
    sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
    sll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(sll)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }

    struct radiotap_header radiotap_hdr;
    radiotap_hdr.it_version = 0;
    radiotap_hdr.it_pad = 0;
    radiotap_hdr.it_len = 0x08;
    radiotap_hdr.it_present = 0;

    struct ieee80211_header wifi_hdr;
    wifi_hdr.frame_control = htons(0x0800);
    wifi_hdr.duration_id = htons(0x0000);
    memset(wifi_hdr.addr1, 0xff, 6); 
    memset(wifi_hdr.addr2, 0x11, 6);
    memset(wifi_hdr.addr3, 0x11, 6);
    wifi_hdr.seq_ctrl = htons(0x0000);

    int buffer_size = 1450;
    char *bufferToSend = malloc(buffer_size);
    char *str_to_append = "TestingTestingTesting";
    int str_to_append_len = strlen(str_to_append);
    int packet_size = sizeof(struct radiotap_header) + sizeof(struct ieee80211_header) + buffer_size;
    unsigned char *complete_packet = (unsigned char *)malloc(packet_size);

    if (RAND_poll() != 1)
    {
        printf("RAND_poll");
        return 1;
    }
    if (RAND_bytes(bufferToSend, buffer_size) != 1)
    {
        printf("RAND_bytes");
        return 1;
    }
    strncpy(bufferToSend + (buffer_size - str_to_append_len), str_to_append, str_to_append_len);
    strncpy(bufferToSend, str_to_append, str_to_append_len);

    memcpy(complete_packet, &radiotap_hdr, sizeof(struct radiotap_header));
    memcpy(complete_packet + sizeof(struct radiotap_header), &wifi_hdr, sizeof(struct ieee80211_header));
    memcpy(complete_packet + sizeof(struct radiotap_header) + sizeof(struct ieee80211_header), bufferToSend, buffer_size);

    int ret = write(sockfd, complete_packet, packet_size);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        perror("write");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("Packet sent successfully\n");

    free(complete_packet);
    free(bufferToSend);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the sniffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <signal.h>

static volatile int keep_running = 1;

void int_handler(int dummy) {
    keep_running = 0;
}


struct radiotap_header
{
    unsigned char it_version;
    unsigned char it_pad;
    unsigned short it_len;
    unsigned int it_present;
};

struct ieee80211_header
{
    unsigned short frame_control;
    unsigned short duration_id;
    unsigned char addr1[6];
    unsigned char addr2[6];
    unsigned char addr3[6];
    unsigned short seq_ctrl;
};

size_t bytes_received = 0;

void packet_handler(const unsigned char *packet, int packet_len)
{
    bytes_received += packet_len;
    struct radiotap_header *radiotap_hdr = (struct radiotap_header *)packet;
    struct ieee80211_header *wifi_hdr = (struct ieee80211_header *)(packet + radiotap_hdr->it_len);
    if (packet_len == 1516){
    printf("Packet size: %d\n", packet_len);

    printf("==============================================\n");
    printf("Received packet:\n");
    printf("Frame Control: 0x%04x\n", ntohs(wifi_hdr->frame_control));
    printf("Duration ID: %d\n", ntohs(wifi_hdr->duration_id));
    printf("Address 1: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", wifi_hdr->addr1[0], wifi_hdr->addr1[1], wifi_hdr->addr1[2], wifi_hdr->addr1[3], wifi_hdr->addr1[4], wifi_hdr->addr1[5]);
    printf("Address 2: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", wifi_hdr->addr2[0], wifi_hdr->addr2[1], wifi_hdr->addr2[2], wifi_hdr->addr2[3], wifi_hdr->addr2[4], wifi_hdr->addr2[5]);
    printf("Address 3: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", wifi_hdr->addr3[0], wifi_hdr->addr3[1], wifi_hdr->addr3[2], wifi_hdr->addr3[3], wifi_hdr->addr3[4], wifi_hdr->addr3[5]);
    printf("Sequence Control: 0x%04x\n", ntohs(wifi_hdr->seq_ctrl));
    printf("radiotap_hdr->it_len: %d\n", radiotap_hdr->it_len);
    printf("sizeof(struct ieee80211_header): %d\n", sizeof(struct ieee80211_header));
    int payload_start = radiotap_hdr->it_len + sizeof(struct ieee80211_header);
    int payload_size = packet_len - payload_start;
    
    printf("Payload start: %d\n", payload_start);
    printf("Payload size: %d\n", payload_size);
    
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Payload at start: \n");
    for (int i = payload_start; i < payload_start + 20; i++){
        printf("%c", packet[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Payload at end: \n");
    for (int i = payload_size - 20; i < packet_len; i++){
        printf("%c", packet[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("==============================================\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <interface>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    signal(SIGINT, int_handler);

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_ll sll;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];

    sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&sll, 0, sizeof(sll));
    sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex(argv[1]);

    if (sll.sll_ifindex == 0)
    {
        perror("if_nametoindex");
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(sll)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Listening on %s...\n", argv[1]);

    while (keep_running)
    {
        int recv_len = recv(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZ, 0);
        if (recv_len < 0)
        {
            perror("recv");
            return 1;
        }

        packet_handler((unsigned char *)buffer, recv_len);
    }

    close(sockfd);

    printf("Total bytes received: %zu\n", bytes_received);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using openssl random header to generate random bytes for a payload. And for sniffer there is an if in packet_handler that is a filter for only packets of length 1516 (filtering only my injected packets).